# How to convert access memo field to text field in access query?

Tags: ms-access

I found this:

```
SELECT [PartsInfoRaw].[Types] as memofield, Replace([PartsInfoRaw].[Types],"","") AS textfield
into newTable FROM [PartsInfoRaw];
```

where Types is a memofield in PartsInfoRaw containing some description. The replace, for some reason, converts the memofield in a textfield. But it feels hacky, and I am not sure if it can
turn sour. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Why do you think there's a need to distinguish between a field returned as memo or as text? Is it because you're running a MakeTable query? If so, that's likely your problem -- MakeTable queries do not belong in a production application. They are useful for quick-and-dirty purposes, and also for creating a temp table that can then be re-used, but you shouldn't need to do it regularly in a production application. If you re-use the same temp table, you can set the data types for each field to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tested this on a [Types] record where the replace function will return more than 255 characters? You will find some of your [textfield] data chopped off.

The Replace function returns a string, so Access is assuming a text type field is appropriate.

I don't know why you have to use a select into other than it is easier than creating a table, deleting all the records and then appending the new data.

Try creating the result table you want first, so you can make sure both fields are type memo. Then turn your query into an Append (Insert Into) query. You will have to run a Delete query first if you only want the results of this query in the newTable table.

```
delete from newTable;
```

Your query as Append:

```
Insert into newTable(memofield, textfield)
SELECT [PartsInfoRaw].[Types] as memofield
     , Replace([PartsInfoRaw].[Types],"","") AS textfield
FROM [PartsInfoRaw];
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish but have you tried Left([MemoField], 255) in your SELECT?

Comment: Try also `Left(Cstr([MemoField]),255)`.